# Same copybook for two files (input/output)

Tags: mainframe, easytrieve

I'm in a situation where it would be helpful to use the same copybook for two different files in an EZT program. I know in COBOL you can use OF to specify which file you would like to get and/or set fields for (i.e. VAR1 OF INFILE). Does Easytrieve have this capability, or do I need to manually define fields with unique names within the program?

Tried using syntax I thought existed where I could add a character to the end to seperate, but tit looks like I'm using that incorrectly.

```
FILE INFILE
%COPYBOOK 1 I.
FILE OUTFILE
%COPYBOOK 1 O.
```

Comment: Based on the lack of response here as well as still not finding any documentation, I am left to assume this is not an available feature of Easytrieve.

Answer (score 0):

A colon to refer to filename:fieldname should work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. either the use filename qualification as suggested by @user2675083 (see [files and fields](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-mainframe-software/devops/ca-easytrieve-report-generator/11-6/programming/code-programs/define-files-and-fields.html) for more details)
2. or you can use macro parameter substitution to add e.g. prefix to a field name and make it unique, example:

> ```
> MSTART MYMAC
> MACRO PARM1                
>   DEFINE &PARM1.FLD W 10 A   VALUE 'HELLO'
> MEND                       
> *                          
> JOB INPUT NULL
>   %MYMAC 'TST'          
>   DISPLAY TSTFLD
>   STOP
> ```

The 'TST' is is passed to the MYMAC macro as positional argument (PARM1), which is used to make the field name unique (the &PARM1.FLD becomes TSTFLD after substitution).

See [process macros](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-mainframe-software/devops/ca-easytrieve-report-generator/11-6/programming/macro-facility/process-macros.html) for more details